# Plotly throws a TypeError when calling Plotly.restyle from a SignalR event

Tags: javascript, plotly, signalr

I'm new to Plotly and I'm trying to do a very simple PoC to update a plot in real-time based on SignalR (WebSocket) events.

I have the following in a Pen that works just fine:

```js
var data = [
  {
    x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
    y: [20, 14, 23],
    type: 'bar'
  }
];


Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);

setTimeout(() => {
  const newData = "\"1,2,3\""; // data is received like this in SignalR
  
  const data = newData.replace(/"/g,"");
  const result = [data.split(',')];
  
  Plotly.restyle('myDiv', 'y', result);
}, 2000);
```

I'm trying now to get it to work in a Vue+SignalR context:

```js
const plotData = [
    {
        x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
        y: [1, 1, 1],
        type: 'bar'
    }
];
Plotly.react('testplot', plotData);
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: data,
    methods: { ... }
);

//...

const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(apiBaseUrl + '/api', {
        accessTokenFactory: () => {
            return generateAccessToken(data.username)
        }
    })
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
    .build();
connection.on('newMessage', onNewMessage);
//...

function onNewMessage(message) {
    const data = message.Text.replace(/"/g, "");
    const result = [data.split(',')];

    Plotly.restyle('testplot', 'y', result); --> error here
};
```

The `result` I'm passing to `restyle` is the same as in the Pen, `[['1', '2', '3']]`.

The error thrown is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at Object.r.coerceTraceIndices (plotly-2.4.2.min.js:58)
    at Object.D [as restyle] (plotly-2.4.2.min.js:58)
    at HubConnection.onNewMessage (index:207)
    at HubConnection.ts:367
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HubConnection.invokeClientMethod (HubConnection.ts:367)
    at HubConnection.processIncomingData (HubConnection.ts:297)
    at WebSocketTransport.HubConnection.connection.onreceive (HubConnection.ts:54)
    at WebSocket.webSocket.onmessage (WebSocketTransport.ts:56)
```

I cannot find anything online to tell me what could cause the error. I'm using `plotly-2.4.2.min.js` in both cases and have tried other versions with the same result.
The error comes from the HTMLElement losing its `data` attribute for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like something happens with Vue (which I'm not familiar with) that kills the `.data` property of the HTMLElement. I tried with this code:

```
var testPlotElemenet = document.getElementById('testplot');

if (testPlotElemenet.data) {
    Plotly.restyle(testPlotElemenet, 'y', result);
}
else {
    var testData = [
        {
            x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
            y: [20, 14, 23],
            type: 'bar'
        }
    ];

    Plotly.react(testPlotElemenet, testData);
    Plotly.restyle(testPlotElemenet, 'y', result);
}
```

And the first time it needs to recreate the plot, but the following messages work and the `.data` property has the expected values.

In the end, since I don't need Vue (it was there from a Microsoft example I was using), I removed all Vue related code and the code works just fine as in CodePen.